# Static getter method returns null, but the property returned is not NULL

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

I have the following static method:

```
public static String getFile2kvleistPath() {
    return file2kvleistPath;
}
```

where file2kvleistPath is a class member defined as follows:

```
public class KvleistNamingConstants {

    private static String file2kvleistPath;

    //.... more code here
}
```

When I debug my application in Eclipse, I see the following in Debugger:

[image]

When I enter the method in Debugger with F5 I see the following:

[image]

How is that possible?! Does it have some name?! Has anybody seen anythin like this?!!

Comment: Step in more until you finished debugging line `150` and your cursor is in line `151` in your case, that should show the value then in stead of `null`

Comment: @RakibulIslam it is not possible to step more, as I am on the deepest level possible - that is, the value of the file2kvleistPath

Answer (score 0):

Restart of Windows helped. I do not have the problem anymore.

Comment: Then, better delete this question to avoid confusion in future for other users.

Comment: The only thing worse than dealing with an issue is dealing with an issue that randomly disappears. Murphy's law dictates that it will happen again at the most inconvenient time.